# How do I exit the command shell after it invokes a Perl script?

Tags: perl, exit, cmd

If I run a Perl script from a command prompt (c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe), how can I exit the command prompt after the script finishes executing.

I tried `system("exit 0")` inside the Perl script but that doesn't exit the cmd prompt shell from where the Perl script is running.

I also tried `exit;` command in the Perl script, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: In bash, you'd invoke the perl script with "exec foo.pl".

Comment: Sorry if i forgot to mention, i am running it in Windows :-)

Comment: This may be difficult to accomplish; the key is to send a SIGHUP signal to the parent process, but at least in ActiveState Perl, getppid() is unimplemented.

Comment: Looks like we have the following approaches :
[1] If i am opening the command shell only for running the perl script, then i can do 
cmd.exe /C perl myscript.pl or 
start.exe /B perl myscript.pl
[2] If i am not already in any command shell and i just want to invoke the perl script, then i can write a batch file which will invoke the script and then call exit. like : perl myscript.pl; exit;

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're starting the command shell just to run the perl script, the answer by Arkaitz Jimenez should work (I voted for it.)

If not, you can create a batch file like `runmyscript.bat`, with content:

```
@echo off
perl myscript.pl
exit
```

The `exit` will end the shell session (and as a side effect, end the batch script itself.)

Answer (score 5):

Try to run the Perl script with a command line like this:

```
perl script.pl & exit
```

The ampersand will start the second command after the first one has finished. You can also use `&&` to execute the second command only if the first succeeded (error code is 0).

Comment: No it is not, look here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @Noufal: In UNIX shells, the command separator is `;` not `&` (which backgrounds a job).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `cmd.exe /C perl yourscript.pl` ?

According to `cmd.exe /?` `/C` carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.

Comment: For that matter, you can just run `perl yourscript.pl` and leave `cmd.exe` out of it entirely.

Comment: On Windows 10, if I start Command Prompt, and only type perl - which will run nothing, how do I close the Command Prompt window that is still open?  Tried quit bye exit  all to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You can start the program in a new window using the [START Dos command](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm). If you call that with `/B` then no additional window is created. Then you can call EXIT to close the current window.

Would that do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a signal to the parent shell from Perl:

```
 kill(9,$PARENT_PID);`
```

Unfortunately, the `getppid()` function is not implemented in Perl on windows so you'll have to find out the parent shell PID via some other means. Also, signal #9 might not be the best choice.

Comment: Do you even have a SIGKILL (signal no. 9) on windows?

Comment: @Noufal: I am sure SIGKILL (as sent from perl) does it job on windows; not sure how it is implemented though